# defining a new pgf class fails

Tags: pgf-core

I want to use the pgf oo library to create a new class. Unfortunately, even this fails:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{oo}

\pgfooclass{mapEntry}{ %
    \method mapEntry() {%
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \pgfoonew \myObj = new mapEntry()
\end{document}
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Runaway argument?
\myObj = new mapEntry() \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfoo@new.
<inserted text> 
            \par
```

Why does it fail? I found literally nothing useful about this, apart from the tikz manual chapter on the oo library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, having spaces around the `=` will break things (even though they are used in the manual). The following code compiles for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{oo}

\pgfooclass{mapEntry}{ %
    \method mapEntry() {%
    }
}

\begin{document}

\pgfoonew \myObj=new mapEntry()

\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason that there can't be a space after the equal sign is that `\pgfoo@new` is defined as `\def\pgfoo@new#1=new #2(#3){...}` (and `\pgfoonew` essentially only calls `\pgf@new` or a variant if there are arguments present).

Comment: Just happened on this one - hadn't seen it before and wish I had since this took me ages to figure out!